# Find files (strictly) older than another file

Tags: file-management, find

When I deploy my software, I ship a zipped file to the target server and extract its contents. In addition to this, at the same time I also place a metadata file in the directory, detailing what was deployed.

If I want to find any files that have been changed since I deployed the software, I can simply find files that have a new modification time than the metadata file:

```
find . -newer deployment_metadata.txt
```

That's nice and straight-forward.

Now, I'd like to also find files that are old than the deployment metadata file. One would assume you could use the bang symbol to negate the "newer" check

```
find . ! -newer deployment_metadata.txt
```

But 'not newer' is not quite equivalent to 'older', as any files with the same timestamp are also "not newer" — so the command also includes all the files that I just deployed!

So, I was wondering if I was missing a trick when it comes to finding (strictly) old files?

My current solution is to create a new file (in the temp dir) using `touch` which has a modification time of one minute before the deployment_metadata.txt file. Then I am able to use the following arguments: `! -newer /var/tmp/metadata_minus_1`.

This works, but seems like a waste of time to have to create, and then clean up, the file in the temp dir - especially as different users may be using my script to check for this (don't want file ownership problems, so I actually go as far as appending `${USER}` to the filename.

Comment: Not sure if it's going to make much difference, but I should have really attached the version of `find` I'm using  

`find --version  
GNU find version 4.2.27  
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to (ab)use epoch time. Here is a test run where I first create seven files in sequence in an empty directory, where the `c#` files get "the same" `ctime` as far as `find` will be concerned:

```
$ for i in a b "c1 c2 c3" d e; do touch $i; sleep 1; done
$ find -newer c2
.
./d
./e
$ find -not -newer c2
./c3
./c2
./a
./b
./c1
$ find -newerct @$(($(stat -c %Z c2)-1))
.
./c3
./d
./c2
./e
./c1
$ find -not -newerct @$(($(stat -c %Z c2)-1))
./a
./b
```

This should represent all possible sets of `ctime` relative to `c2`:

1. `ctime` > `c2`
2. `ctime` ≤ `c2`
3. `ctime` ≥ `c2`
4. `ctime` < `c2`

with somewhat fuzzy matching, at least.

The third command gets epoch `ctime` for the file `c2`, subtracts 1 via shell arithmetic and feeds this as reference to `-newerct` (the `@` is needed for `find` to interpret is as such a timestamp) to find all files with `ctime` newer than this interpreted timestamp (see `-newerXY` in `man find`). The fourth command negates this match, and should in practice do what you want if I've understood the question correctly, if you put your reference file as `c2` in my example.

Note that the "1 second" offset is somewhat arbitrary (which is what I meant by "fuzzy matching"), and one could imagine a situation where a bug could be constructed. However, timestamps of files are not "definite" anyway and can not be trusted to be, so I can't imagine it to generate either security or practical problems in real situations.

Actually, in practice you might even want to *increase* the 1 second offset (I see in your question that you use 1 minute right now), but that is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe pipe the `find` output into a loop of the `test` command which will let you use an "older-than" test:

```
find ... | while read file;
do
  [ "$file" -ot deployment_metadata.txt ] && echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: This works even in dash!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find all files older than an existing file, and following the accepted solution:

```
find . -type f -not -newer spec-file
```

This includes 'spec-file' in the results, which makes it not correct for removing the file results.

I used the following to find the newest file I wanted to remove:

```
find . -type f -not -newer spec-file -printf '%T+  %p\n' | sort | tail -3
```

And then used the second to last file to remove them:

```
find . -type f -not -newer result-file -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Preliminary note

The purpose of this answer is to provide code that is strict and portable (for comparison: `find … -newerct …` from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/635229/432690) and `[ … -ot …` from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/635215/432690) are not portable).

---

#### Basic solution

For every file that passes your `! -newer deployment_metadata.txt`, check if `deployment_metadata.txt` is `-newer`:

```
find . ! -newer deployment_metadata.txt -exec sh -c '
   [ -n "$(find deployment_metadata.txt -prune -newer "$1")" ]
' find-sh {} \; -print
```

---

#### Notes

- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- `-prune` is in case `deployment_metadata.txt` is a directory.
- `[ -n "$(find …)" ]` converts the non-empty or empty output from the inner `find` into exit status `0` or `1` respectively, this becomes the exit status of `sh`; then `-exec` of the outer `find` evaluates as true or false respectively.
- We want to know if the resulting string is empty or not, it can either be empty or be exactly the name of the reference file (`deployment_metadata.txt` in our case). If the name of the reference file contained newline characters *only*, remember `$(…)` strips all trailing newlines; in this case our test would not be able to tell the two possibilities apart. To solve this problem you should supply a broader path, e.g. `./…`. The problem occurs only for a basename consisting of nothing but newline character(s); in practice you don't need to care, unless you deliberately use such name instead of `deployment_metadata.txt`.
- In `[`, `-n` is the default. I used `-n` explicitly in case the name of the reference file starts with `-` and could be interpreted by `[` as an option. The point is not every implementation of `[` is smart enough to recognize the default case early by the fact there is exactly one argument before `]`. The name of your reference file is `deployment_metadata.txt` and it's save anyway, but if you ever want to use `-whatever` then with the explicit `-n` it should still work.
- We need a shell to make `$(…)` work. There will be one `sh` and one `find` for every file that passes your original test. Creating a new process is relatively slow, so the solution may perform poorly.
- Our `-exec` is enough to test what we want. This means `! -newer deployment_metadata.txt` is not strictly needed. It's useful though, it improves the performance. Each time `! -newer` evaluates to false, our costly `-exec` is not evaluated. Without this preliminary test the `-exec` would be evaluated for every file tested by the outer `find`.
- You can add more tests/actions before our `-exec` or/and directly before (or instead of) `-print`. Our whole `-exec … \;` is equivalent to hypothetical `-older deployment_metadata.txt` you'd like to have. This is the beauty of `find`: with `-exec` you can build virtually any test.

---

#### Possible improvement

If all you want is to `-print` the result, the method can be optimized slightly:

```
find . ! -newer deployment_metadata.txt -exec sh -c '
   for f do
      [ -n "$(find deployment_metadata.txt -prune -newer "$f")" ] \
      && printf "%s\n" "$f"
   done
' find-sh {} +
```

In this approach one `sh` will serve multiple pathnames supplied by the outer `find` (still `find` can run multiple `sh` processes in sequence, in case all of the pathnames to be served would trigger `argument list too long` error, `find` is that smart). This way we lower the number of `sh` processes. We added `printf`, but `printf` is a builtin in virtually any implementation of `sh` and as such it runs as a part of the `sh` process, not a separate process.

You can still add more `find`-specific tests before our `-exec`, but not after (well, technically you can, but this won't work as expected because `-exec … +` always evaluates as true). Properly crafted shell code just before (or instead of) `printf` may work as further tests, but because it will probably involve spawning additional processes, it will defy the purpose.