# What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?

Tags: shell-script, sh, positional-parameter

#### Question

I encountered the following snippet:

```
sh -c 'some shell code' sh …
```

(where `…` denotes zero or more additional arguments).

I know the first `sh` is the command. I know `sh -c` is supposed to execute the provided shell code (i.e. `some shell code`). What is the purpose of the second `sh`?

---

#### Disclaimer

Similar or related question sometimes appears as a follow-up question after `sh -c` is properly used in an answer and the asker (or another user) wants to know in detail how the answer works. Or it may be a part of a bigger question of the type "what does this code do?". The purpose of the current question is to provide a canonical answer below.

The main question, similar or related questions covered here are:

1. What is the second `sh` in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh …`?
2. What is the second `bash` in `bash -c 'some shell code' bash …`?
3. What is `find-sh` in `find . -exec sh -c 'some shell code' find-sh {} \;`?
4. If `some shell code` was in a shell script and we called `./myscript foo …`, then `foo` would be referred to as `$1` inside the script. But `sh -c 'some shell code' foo …` (or `bash -c …`) refers to `foo` as `$0`. Why the discrepancy?
5. What is wrong with using `sh -c 'some shell code' foo …` where `foo` is a "random" argument? In particular:

   - `sh -c 'some shell code' "$variable"`
   - `sh -c 'some shell code' "$@"`
   - `find . -exec sh -c 'some shell code' {} \;`
   - `find . -exec sh -c 'some shell code' {} +`

   I mean I can use `$0` instead of `$1` inside `some shell code`, it doesn't bother me. What bad can happen?

Some of the above may be considered duplicates (possibly cross-site duplicates) of existing questions (e.g. [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152391/108618)). Still I haven't found a question/answer that aims at explaining the issue to beginners who want to understand `sh -c …` and its allegedly useless extra argument observed in high quality answers. This question fills the gap.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Preliminary note

It's quite uncommon to see `sh -c 'some shell code'` invoked directly from a shell. In practice, if you're in a shell then you will probably choose to use the same shell (or its subshell) to execute `some shell code`. It's quite common to see `sh -c` invoked from within another tool like `find -exec`.

Nevertheless most of this answer elaborates on `sh -c` represented as a standalone command (which it is) because the main issue depends solely on `sh`. Later on few examples and hints use `find` where it seems useful and/or educative.

---

#### Basic answer

> What is the second `sh` in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh …`?

It's an arbitrary string. Its purpose is to provide a meaningful name to use in warning and error messages. Here it's `sh` but it might be `foo`, `shell1` or `special purpose shell` (properly quoted to include spaces).

Bash and other POSIX-compliant shells work in the same way when it comes to `-c`. While I find [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) to be too formal to cite here, an excerpt from `man 1 bash` is quite straightforward:

> ```
> bash [options] [command_string | file]
> ```
>
> `-c`
> If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument `command_string`. If there are arguments after the  `command_string`, the  first  argument  is assigned to `$0` and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. The assignment to `$0` sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

In our case `some shell code` is the `command_string` and this second `sh` is "the first argument after". It is assigned to `$0` in the context of `some shell code`.

This way the error from `sh -c 'nonexistent-command' "special purpose shell"` is:

```
special purpose shell: nonexistent-command: command not found
```

and you immediately know which shell it comes from. This is useful if you have many `sh -c` invocations. "The first argument after the `command_string`" may not be supplied at all; in such case `sh` (string) will be assigned to `$0` if the shell is `sh`, `bash` if the shell is `bash`. Therefore these are equivalent:

```
sh -c 'some shell code' sh
sh -c 'some shell code'
```

But if you need to pass at least one argument after `some shell code` (i.e. maybe arguments that should be assigned to `$1`, `$2`, …) then there is no way to omit the one that will be assigned to `$0`.

---

#### Discrepancy?

> If `some shell code` was in a shell script and we called `./myscript foo …`, then `foo` would be referred to as `$1` inside the script. But `sh -c 'some shell code' foo …` (or `bash -c …`) refers to `foo` as `$0`. Why the discrepancy?

Normally a shell interpreting a script gets the name of the script (e.g. `./myscript`) as the zeroth entry in the array of arguments, available later as `$0`. Then the name will be used in warning and error messages. Usually this behavior is perfectly OK and there is no need to provide `$0` manually. On the other hand with `sh -c` there is no script to get a name from. Still some meaningful name is useful, hence the way to provide it.

The discrepancy will vanish if you stop considering the first argument after `some shell code` as a (kind of) positional parameter for the code. If `some shell code` is in a script named `myscript` and you call `./myscript foo …`, then the equivalent code with `sh -c` will be:

```
sh -c 'some shell code' ./myscript foo …
```

Here `./myscript` is just a string, it looks like a path but this path may not exist; the string may be different in the first place. This way the same shell code can be used. The shell will assign `foo` to `$1` in both cases. No discrepancy.

---

#### Pitfalls of treating `$0` like `$1`

> What is wrong in using `sh -c 'some shell code' foo …` where foo is a "random" argument? […] I mean I can use `$0` instead of `$1` inside `some shell code`, it doesn't bother me. What bad can happen?

In many cases this will work. There are arguments against this approach though.

1. The most obvious pitfall is you may get misleading warnings or errors from the invoked shell. Remember they will start with whatever `$0` expands to in the context of the shell. Consider this snippet:

   ```
   sh -c 'eecho "$0"' foo    # typo intended
   ```

   The error is:

   ```
   foo: eecho: command not found
   ```

   and you may wonder if `foo` was treated as a command. It is not that bad if `foo` is hardcoded and unique; at least you know the error has something to do with `foo`, so it brings your attention to this very line of code. It can be worse:

   ```
   # as regular user
   sh -c 'ls "$0" > "$1"/' "$HOME" "/root/foo"
   ```

   The output:

   ```
   /home/kamil: /root/foo: Permission denied
   ```

   The first reaction is: what happened to my home directory? Another example:

   ```
   find /etc/fs* -exec sh -c '<<EOF' {} \;    # insane shell code intended
   ```

   Possible output:

   ```
   /etc/fstab: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
   ```

   It's very easy to think there's something wrong with `/etc/fstab`; or to wonder why the code wants to interpret it as here-document.

   Now run these commands and see how accurate the errors are when we provide meaningful names:

   ```
   sh -c 'eecho "$1"' "shell with echo" foo    # typo intended
   sh -c 'ls "$1" > "$2"/' my-special-shell "$HOME" "/root/foo"
   find /etc/fs* -exec sh -c '<<EOF' find-sh {} \;    # insane shell code intended
   ```
2. `some shell code` is not identical to what it would be in a script. This is directly related to the alleged discrepancy elaborated above. It may not be a problem at all; still at some level of shell-fu you may appreciate consistency.
3. Similarly at some level you may find yourself enjoying scripting in the Right Way. Then even if you can get away with using `$0`, you won't do this because this is not how things are supposed to work.
4. If you want to pass more than one argument or if the number of arguments is not known in advance and you need to process them in sequence, then using `$0` for one of them is a bad idea. `$0` is by design different than `$1` or `$2`. This fact will manifest itself if `some shell code` uses one or more of the following:

   - `$#` – The number of positional parameters does not take `$0` into account because `$0` is not a positional parameter.
   - `$@` or `$*` – `"$@"` is like `"$1", "$2", …`, there is no `"$0"` in this sequence.
   - `for f do` (equivalent to `for f in "$@"; do`) – `$0` is never assigned to `$f`.
   - `shift` ([`shift [n]`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#shift) in general) – Positional parameters are shifted, `$0` stays intact.

   In particular consider this scenario:

   1. You start with code like this:

      ```
      find . -exec sh -c 'some shell code referring "$1"' find-sh {} \;
      ```
   2. You notice it runs one `sh` per file. This is suboptimal.
   3. You know `-exec … \;` replaces `{}` with one filename but `-exec … {} +` replaces `{}` with possibly many filenames. You take advantage of the latter and introduce a loop:

      ```
      find . -exec sh -c '
         for f do
            some shell code referring "$f"
         done
      ' find-sh {} +
      ```

   Such optimization is a good thing. But if you start with this:

   ```
   # not exactly right but you will get away with this
   find . -exec sh -c 'some shell code referring "$0"' {} \;
   ```

   and turn it into this:

   ```
   # flawed
   find . -exec sh -c '
      for f do
         some shell code referring "$f"
      done
   ' {} +
   ```

   then you will introduce a bug: the very first file coming from the expansion of `{}` won't be processed by `some shell code referring "$f"`. Note `-exec sh -c … {} +` runs `sh` with as many arguments as it can, but there are limits for this and if there are many, many files then one `sh` will not be enough, another `sh` process will be spawned by `find` (and possibly another, and another, …). With each `sh` you will skip (i.e. not process) one file.

   To test this in practice replace the string `some shell code referring` with `echo` and run the resulting code snippets in a directory with few files. The last snippet won't print `.`.

   All this doesn't mean you shouldn't use `$0` in `some shell code` at all. You can and shall use `$0` for things it was designed for. E.g. if you want `some shell code` to print a (custom) warning or error then make the message start with `$0`. Provide a meaningful name after `some shell code` and enjoy meaningful errors (if any) instead of vague or misleading ones.

---

#### Final hints:

- With `find … -exec sh -c …` [never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).
- For the same reasons `some shell code` should not contain fragments expanded by the current shell, unless you really really know the expanded values are safe for sure. The best practice is to single-quote the entire code (like in the examples above, it's always `'some shell code'`) and pass every non-fixed value as a separate argument. Such argument is safely retrievable from a positional parameter within the inner shell. Exporting variables is also safe. Run this and analyze output of each `sh -c …` (desired output is `foo';date'`):

  ```
  variable="foo';date'"

  # wrong
  sh -c "echo '$variable'" my-sh

  # right
  sh -c 'echo "$1"' my-sh "$variable"

  # also right
  export variable
  sh -c 'echo "$variable"' my-sh
  ```
- If you run `sh -c 'some shell code' …` in a shell, the shell will remove single-quotes embracing `some shell code`; then the inner shell (`sh`) will parse `some shell code`. It's important to quote right also in this context. You may find this useful: [**Parameter expansion and quotes within quotes**](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690).