# find -exec with wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am trying to use bash 'find' to process all folders that contain a .log file and get their sizes. However the wildcard is not working as expected.  This returns nothing:

```
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/*.log' \; -exec du -d0 '{}' \;
```

however if I replace `*.log` with `foo.log`, then it works as expected for directories containing that file name.

Based on some similar SE posts, I tried:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'test -e "{}/*.log"' \; -exec du -d0 '{}' \;
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'test -e "$1/*.log"' '{}' \; -exec du -d0 '{}' \;
```

but those don't work any better.

Comment: `test` does not support checking for matches to a glob (wildcard) pattern, just for existence of specific filenames. Do the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash) solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

With `find … -exec test -e '{}/*.log'` you're passing a string like `something/*.log` to `test`, where `*` is *literal*. Neither tool treats it as a wildcard. Some implementations of `find` won't even expand `{}` if it's a part of an argument (as opposed to `{}` being a whole argument).

One of your later tries embeds `{}` in the shell code. [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). The other try is better in this matter, you're close to a solution. This will *kinda* work:

```
# still flawed though
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'test -e "$1/"*.log' bash '{}' \; -exec du -d0 '{}' \;
```

See [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690). The main "fix" however is in not quoting the asterisk in the shell code. This way it's a wildcard in the inner shell (but not in the outer shell, it's properly single-quoted there). The problem is `*.log` may expand to more than one word (if there are many matching files) and this case will break the `test` invocation.

The following code will find directories with `*.log` files:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   for f in "$1/"*.log; do test -e "$f" && exit 0; done; exit 1
' sh {} \; -print
```

The code is portable. There's no need for inner `bash`, `sh` should be faster. Replace `-print` with `-exec du …` if you wish.

This works by returning success (`exit 0`) from the inner shell as soon as `test` confirms existence of some matching file¹. Not-yet-tested matching files (if any) will not be tested in vain, this saves time. If there is no match then the pattern will stay literal, `test` will fail and the whole shell will exit with failure (`exit 1`). Remember `-exec` is also a test, so it affects if `-print` (or `-exec du …` or whatever you put there) is performed.

---

Another approach may be to let `find` itself find matching files with

```
find . -name '*.log' … -print
```

and to parse its output to isolate directory names, finally to use `xargs` with `du`. Directories could appear multiple times, newlines in pathnames would require non-portable code (starting from `-print0`). I think this would be unnecessarily complicated. Finding directories seems superior.

---

¹ Note `test -e` tells you if there's a file [which may be a directory or whatever](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). To confirm existence of a regular file use `test -f`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to find/scan for log files and then collect the unique directory names.

This `find` command should pull out the directories, adding `uniq` to remove duplicates. The `-z`/`-0` flags help ensure pathnames with newlines/spaces/ quotes are parsed flawlessly:

```
find . -type f -name \*.log -exec dirname -z {} \+ | uniq -z | xargs -0 -r du -d0
```

Add `| sort -rn |head` if searching for the biggest disc usage.