# grep for lines in shell script, send to xargs with $1 set

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

I have a shell script (I use GNU bash 4.4.20 on Ubuntu 18.04) with a list of commands I often run, e.g.:

```
sudo program1 $1 foo arg1
sudo program2 $1 foo arg2
sudo program1 $1 bar arg3
sudo program2 $1 bar arg4
```

I'd like to grep for select lines in this script and run them. For example if I'd like to run lines 3 and 4 above with $1 set to "some_value", I was thinking something like this would work:

```
set some_value; grep bar my_shell_script.sh | xargs -L1
```

I think my problems are 1) I'm not sure how to use xargs if the command itself is embedded in the input and 2) I'm not sure how to set $1 in the context of xargs if it's receiving its input from grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lines of what you tried:

```
grep bar my_shell_script.sh | bash -- /dev/stdin some_value
```

Note in the above code the stdin of the new `bash` comes from `grep`. If the new `bash` runs a command that also reads from stdin then the command will read from `grep`. To be on the safe side or if you explicitly want to use the stdin for something else, use this syntax:

```
bash <(grep bar my_shell_script.sh) my-bash some_value
# or
bash -c "$(grep bar my_shell_script.sh)" my-bash some_value
```

Or if you want the code to be executed in the current shell:

```
. <(grep bar my_shell_script.sh) some_value
```

Notes:

- [Don't you want to quote `$1` in your file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)
- Process substitution (`<(…)`) is not portable. You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), Bash supports it. Command substitution (`$(…)`) is portable but it will fail with `argument list too long` if the output from `grep` is too long.
- `my-bash` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690) (the explanation is in the context of `sh -c`/`bash -c`).
- `/dev/stdin` may or may not exist in your OS.
- This answer does not discuss (in)sanity of running code by filtering a "script" with `grep`. In this matter I assume you know what you want.

Comment: This works great. Agreed about quoting $1 in reality, I just made up that example for brevity. Also agreed that grepping commands out of a script is somewhat insane - in my case I think it makes sense but it'd require way too much context to get 2nd opinions on that. I was surprised that xargs doesn't have a mode that takes the command from its input! I guess there's security considerations in allowing that.

Comment: @nonagon IMO it's not about security. `xargs` is designed to run some executable with arguments taken from stdin. I mean the name of the executable *does not* come from stdin, it's *fixed* when `xargs` starts and this is *by design*. You can circumvent this with `env` being the executable (`… | xargs -L1 env --`). But to expand `$1` (or like) you need a shell anyway. The basic task of `xargs` is word splitting, a shell can do this as well. If your file is "a *shell* script" then it should be interpreted by a shell.