# How to bulk delete zip files without extention in linux

Tags: zip, bash-scripting

I have a folder full of different files but without extension. How can I delete all files that are zip files?

Comment: Hint: [file Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/file.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Kubuntu the following command:

```
file -b --mime-type path/to/some/zip
```

returns:

```
application/zip
```

I can use it to detect all zip files in the current directory (with subdirectries). The command is:

```sh
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
   for f do
   file -b --mime-type "$f" | grep -q "^application/zip$" && {
      printf "%s\n" "$f"
      # rm "$f"
      } 
   done
' find-sh {} +
```

If the result looks sane, uncomment `rm "$f"` (delete `#`) to actually remove the files.

Notes:

- Neither `-b` nor `--mime-type` are portable options of `file`. If your `file` does not support them then check what bare `file path/to/some/zip` prints. It may be:

  ```
  path/to/some/zip: Zip archive data, …
  ```

  Where `…` denotes additional information. If I needed to rely on this output then my `grep` command would be:

  ```
  grep -q ": Zip archive data"
  ```

  but it would (possibly) falsely detect files with this very string in the name. Anyway, adjust your `grep` to what your `file` prints.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- The command does not care about filenames (in Linux what you call "extension" is just a part of filename). It answers the question you asked in the body of the post ("How can I delete all files that are zip files?"), not the title ("How to bulk delete zip files *without extension*").