# How to create symbolic links to each file in all subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

i had the follow structure of Folder/File, for example

```
./3DO Company, The - 3DO/goldstar.bin
./3DO Company, The - 3DO/panafz10e-anvil.bin
./Arcade/pgm.zip
./Arcade/skns.zip
./Atari - 400-800/ATARIBAS.ROM
./Atari - 5200/5200.rom
./Atari - 7800/7800 BIOS (E).rom
./Atari - Lynx/lynxboot.img
./Coleco - ColecoVision/coleco.rom
```

that is just for star arrange the folder/files but i need symbolic links to each file on all sub-folders (not copy, just thing i not have enough free space for make copies) but i need full name of file including special characters and just using releative path, not the absolute path.

well i know using a loop, like "for" is possible, i had the idea but i don't have a correct command for do this under bash in GNU/Linux.

the result i searching is :

```
./goldstar.bin
./panafz10e-anvil.bin
./pgm.zip
./skns.zip
./ATARIBAS.ROM
./5200.rom
./7800 BIOS (E).rom
./lynxboot.img
./coleco.rom
```

Someone can help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `find`, basic solution:

```
# remember to cd to the right directory first
find . -exec ln -s {} ./ \;
```

Caveats:

- The basic solution will try to create symbolic links to all [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), including files of the type directory; you probably want links to regular files only, so `-type f` is a good idea.
- Attempts to link to files directly under `.` and to `.` itself will fail (`file exists`) because the paths are taken (edge case: if such file is removed after `find` spots it but before `ln` acts then a symbolic link leading to itself will be created; compare [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)). With [GNU `find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Finding-Files) `-mindepth 2` allows you to skip these files; [posixly](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (portably) you can check if there are at least two slashes in the path: `-path './*/*'`.

The improved command is:

```
find . -type f -path './*/*' -exec ln -s {} ./ \;
```

This is still sub-optimal because the command runs a separate `ln` for each matching file. If your `ln` supports `-t` then `-exec ln -s -t ./ {} +` will work. A portable improvement is:

```
find . -type f -path './*/*' -exec sh -c 'ln -s "$@" ./' find-sh {} +
```

The point is `-exec … {} +` can process many pathnames at once, but `{}` must be just before `+`, so `-exec ln -s {} ./ +` would not work. In shell code `$@` can be anywhere. By using a shell we can make one portable `ls` handle multiple pathnames passed by `find`. `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

If a symbolic link is going to be created and the name is already taken in the current working directory then the link won't be created and the existing file won't be overwritten.

"Already taken" may refer to a symbolic link created a moment earlier. This means if there are regular files with the same name (obviously in different directories) then at most one symbolic link with the name will be created (expect `file exists` errors). The target of the symbolic link will be the first file of the bunch. In general you cannot easily predict the order (I think any(?) `find` uses the [directory order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13451/108618), recursively), so you cannot easily guess which of the files with the same name will be linked to.

To observe what is being processed, add `-print` at the very end (`ln -v` is an alternative, not portable though). The final portable command is:

```
find . -type f -path './*/*' -exec sh -c 'ln -s "$@" ./' find-sh {} + -print
```

Note `-exec … {} +` is always evaluated as true, what it does cannot affect `-print`. If `-print` prints some pathname, it only means an attempt to crate a symbolic link was made; it does not mean the attempt succeeded. If you want to print only successfully linked pathnames then you need `-exec ln -s {} ./ \; -print`. This will work because `-exec … \;` is evaluated as true or false according to the exit status of the command inside, so if `ln` fails then `-print` will not print the pathname.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaniations :D