# Why is xargs unable to call basename properly in a subshell?

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I ran into the following problem:

```
user@machine:/$ echo ./dir/fil | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo $(basename {})"
./dir/fil
```

Why is it not just printing `fil`?

So `basename` seems to get the expected parameter `./dir/fil` but somehow assumes it is all the filename. Conversly when used with `dirname` it only prints out `.`. It feels as if the `/`s are somehow escaped.

Why do I care?

I actually need to run something like this:

```
find -name "*.foo" | xargs -I {} bash -c "cd $(dirname \"{}\"); thirdpartytool $(basename \"{}\") 2>&1 > /dev/null | sort"
```

- I need a non-zero return code if any call of `thirdpartytool` returns one, so `find ... -exec ...` does not work for me.
- I need output redirection (discard stdout and sort stderr) so I need to call another shell.
- I need to `cd` because `thirdpartytool` must be called from the directory where the file is, so I need `dirname` and `basename` in a subshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> echo ./dir/fil | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo $(basename {})"
> ```

Here `$(basename {})` is double-quoted and therefore *it gets expanded by the current shell before `xargs` even runs*. The output from `basename {}` is `{}`, so the command becomes:

```
echo ./dir/fil | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo {}"
```

It would be different if you single-quoted the shell code. Still [embedding `{}` in shell code is wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). You should pass the result of expansion of `{}` as positional parameter(s).

Eventually you want to use `find`. The truly robust command will be in a form of `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` (if supported) or [`find … -exec …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/108618).

If I understand your goal right, your command will be like:

```
find . -name "*.foo" -print0 \
| xargs -0 -L1 sh -c 'cd "$(dirname "$1")" && thirdpartytool "$(basename "$1")" 2>&1 >/dev/null | sort' sh
```

where

- I fixed the quoting,
- I made sure the `thirdpartytool` runs only if `cd` succeeds,
- I used `sh` because there is nothing specific to Bash in the shell code.

Additional notes:

- Instead of calling `dirname` and `basename` you can [make the shell do the job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253524/108618).
- The second `sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

Comment: Thanks! Not only do I have a working command now but I also learned a lot!