# How to insert argument separating space into brace expansion preamble?

Tags: bash

I want to use brace expansion to generate the following argument sequence: `./some_command -c root.foo -c root.bar -c root.baz`. Brace expansion at first glance looks as a perfect tool: use `-c root.` as a preamble and `{foo,bar,baz}` inside braces. However, preamble cannot contain field separators:

- `./some_command -c root.{foo,bar,baz}` expands to `-c root.foo root.bar root.baz` (obviously)
- `./some_command -c\ root.{foo,bar,baz}` expands to `-c\ root.foo -c\ root.bar -c\ root.baz` (obviously again). Here I get three arguments instead of six desired.

Is it possible to make a preamble with an argument separator?

Comment: Some tools treat `-c whatever` and `-cwhatever` equivalently. If `./some_command` is one of them, then use `./some_command -croot.{foo,bar,baz}`.

Comment: In fact this is a [convention encouraged by The Open Group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap12.html): "If the SYNOPSIS of a standard utility shows an option with a mandatory option-argument (as with `[ -c option_argument]` in the example), a conforming application shall use separate arguments for that option and its option-argument. However, a conforming implementation shall also permit applications to specify the option and option-argument in the same argument string without intervening <blank> characters."

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It solved my current case, thanks (XY problem detected). The question is more general and may still be useful though, so I'm leaving it open and would be glad to receive the answer for the original problem.

Comment: Remotely related: [*Pass each find result as an argument with prefix to exec*](https://superuser.com/q/1722419/432690).

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate brace expansions to get the cross product

```sh
echo ./some_command {"-c root."}{foo,bar,baz}
```

***However***

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and **at least one unquoted comma** or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

-- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion

So this *might* be OK

```sh
$ echo ./some_command {"-c root.",#}{foo,bar,baz}
./some_command -c root.foo -c root.bar -c root.baz #foo #bar #baz
```

The `-c root.foo` is considered a single word, so you might need to `eval`.

The best way to do this is to use arrays:

```bash
options=()
for arg in {foo,bar,baz}; do options+=( -c "root.$arg" ); done
echo ./some_command "${options[@]}"
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the first part of this answer. First you correctly notice that `{"-c root."}` in `{"-c root."}{foo,bar,baz}` does not expand, then you deal with this "problem" by introducing `{"-c root.",#}` which gives you words that start with `#`. They are not comments (your `echo` did print them), unless you `eval` the result. It so happens `eval` is a "solution" to the problem of `-c root.foo` being a single word, but the OP had this exact problem from `-c\ root.{foo,bar,baz}`. Why don't we just `eval` *this*? Why complicate things with the additional brace expansion and `#`?