# Find folders that contain only one specific file (.DS_Store) and no others?

Tags: macos, terminal, find, .ds-store

Is there some way to use the `find` command in macOS terminal to find all folders recursively within a given path that are *virtually empty*, or empty aside from a single .DS_Store file?

I've tried the following in terminal to no avail:

```
find TARGET_PATH -empty -type d
```

Apparently, these super-invisible .DS_Store files are still considered folder contents ***even in the absence of any other files***. :/

This question is about a smaller part of a larger task I'm trying to accomplish. I've almost got it all working now except part of the script that only seems to work when I run it from terminal directly. Here's a link to the main issue in case anyone reading this question might be able to help: [Service to execute series of commands on selected folders to eliminate issues with .DS_Store files in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/1732814/service-to-execute-series-of-commands-on-selected-folders-to-eliminate-issues-wi)

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? You've asked several probably related questions recently about .DS_Store files, yet it's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: It's rather complicated. Perhaps I should ask the *big* question, show what I've got so far, and go from there.

Comment: Possibly. Sometimes an overall 'mission statement' can push an enquiry in a different direction. At the moment it kind of feels like you're trying to find them & set to a specific date, or remove them [either of which will work until the next time you open the window;) If you just want to bin them, such as Cocktail, Onyx, Tinker Tool all have a drag & drop 'sweeper', though interestingly, it doesn't seem to make it forget all prior parameters. I never figured out where it stores the rest.

Comment: I posted the info on the main task I'm trying to accomplish here: https://superuser.com/questions/1732814/service-to-execute-series-of-commands-on-selected-folders-to-eliminate-issues-wi

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

The following `find` command does what I think you want:

```
braces={} find TARGET_PATH -type d \( -empty -o -exec sh -c '
   echo | find "$1" ! \( -type f -name .DS_Store \) -exec sh -c "
      for f do read dummy || { kill -s INT \"\$PPID\"; exit 1; } ; done
   " inner-sh "$braces" +
' outer-sh {} \; \) -print
```

---

#### Explanation

The command prints directories for which `-empty` evaluates to true or a custom `-exec` test evaluates to true. The custom test is designed to ignore regular files named `.DS_Store` and to tell if it sees a given directory as empty then.

The custom test is an `sh` process named [`outer-sh`](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690). From the main `find` it gets exactly one pathname of a directory. It runs another `find` with the directory as a single starting point. This inner `find` is designed to ignore regular files with the name `.DS_Store`. It finds at least its starting point, possibly more [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). It passes them to another custom "test", an `sh` process named `inner-sh`. This time it's `-exec … +`, so possibly more than one pathname is provided to `sh`. I call it "test" (with quotes) because it's not really a test in the context of `find`; its job is not to test something for the `find` that runs it; its job is to kill this `find` in some circumstances.

The inner custom "test" is designed to tell if it got more than one positional argument. It could simply check its `$#`, but the inner `find` is allowed to decide that even two pathnames generate a command line that is too long, it is allowed to invoke `sh` with one argument, leaving remaining pathnames (if any) for separate `sh` process(es). Here a trick with `echo` kicks in.

The trick with `echo` is this sole `echo` piped to the inner `find`. Sole `echo` prints exactly one empty line (i.e. one newline character). The inner `find` does not read from its stdin, but our inner `sh` "test(s)" may; and they do. For each pathname `read dummy` is performed. The first pathname is the starting point of the inner `find`, `read dummy` will consume the line from `echo`, it will succeed. The second pathname may or may not be provided (depending if the directory is non-empty or empty after ignoring possible `.DS_Store`); if it's provided then there will be another `read dummy` and it will fail (regardless if performed by the same `sh` as the first one or not; this is the trick).

If `read dummy` fails then the shell performing the inner "test" will kill its parent and exit. The parent is the inner `find`. Killing it makes it stop processing files and spawning more `sh`s, even if otherwise it was going to.

In other words, if in the directory there is a file other than `.DS_Store` then there will be `read dummy` that will fail and this will lead to killing the inner `find`, so the exit status from the inner `find` seen by the outer `sh` will be non-zero.

<sup>In case the inner `find` notices the demise of the inner `sh` before noticing the signal, and if there's nothing more for it to do, it may(?) exit by itself. The inner `sh` exits with failure (`exit 1`) after the `kill`, so even then the inner `find` will exit with a non-zero exit status (`-exec utility … +` is always true as a test, but if the utility fails then `find` shall return non-zero exit status). I doubt this scenario of `find` exiting before it's killed (when it's going to be killed) is possible, I suppose it should react to the signal first. `exit 1` is just in case I'm wrong.</sup>

So if in the directory there is a file other than `.DS_Store`, the outer `sh` will see the inner `find` failing, it will itself exit with a non-zero exit status. This will be interpreted by the outer `find` as the custom test evaluated as false, so `-print` will not be performed.

If in the directory there is no file other than `.DS_Store` then there will be exactly one inner `sh` and exactly one `read dummy`. There will be no `kill`. Several things will succeed in sequence: `read`, the inner `sh`, the inner `find`, the outer `sh`; and then the outer `find` will consider the custom test evaluated as true, so `-print` will be performed.

---

#### Notes

- I deliberately kept everything inside the main `find` (as opposed to e.g. `find … | awk …`), so now you can add something (`-exec …`, `-delete`, …) after, before or instead of `-print`.
- About `braces={}`. If I literally used `{}` where the inner `find … -exec …` expects it, it might be expanded by the *outer* `find` (depending on implementation) and totally break the code. By storing `{}` as a variable in the environment and letting the right shell expand it, I hid this `{}` from the outer `find`.
- The custom test runs several processes per tested directory. Do not expect the whole command to perform as well as `find TARGET_PATH -type d -empty`.
- You used `-empty`, so I know your `find` supports it. In general `-empty` is not a portable operand. Our custom test allows you to remove `-empty -o` from the code (and then the outermost `\(` `\)` pair is not needed, it may stay though). The custom test itself detects truly empty directories. This means you can use the solution with implementations of `find` that don't support `-empty`. Still, thanks to how `-o` works (`-test1 -o -test2` skips `-test2` if `-test1` returns true), if you can use `-empty` then use it because for truly empty directories it speeds things up.
- In the inner `find` I could use `-exec … \;` instead of `-exec … +`. A dilemma: is it better to use `+` and let `find` query the filesystem ahead to build a possibly large list to provide to the inner `sh`, when at most two pathnames suffice? or is it better to use `\;` and often spawn two inner `sh` processes, but without a need of reading from the filesystem ahead (and without the `for` loop)? The trick with `echo` allows us to use `\;` and you can test which variant is better for you. In my tests on a reasonably large directory tree `+` was overall slightly faster, but your mileage may vary.

  If you ever need to use the solution with some old `find` that doesn't support `-exec … +`, convert to `-exec … \;` freely.
- To tell if a directory is empty, `-empty` needs a read permission on the directory. If reading is not permitted and therefore `-empty` cannot know if the directory is empty then it will assume non-empty and evaluate as false. As far as I tested, our custom test behaves in the same way; so regardless if you use it with or without `-empty -o`, you should get results you would get from `-empty` if you could tell it to ignore `.DS_Store` files.

  The difference is our code prints (to stderr) more "copies" of `permission denied` per directory without read permission. I don't expect this to ever be a problem.
- To tell if a directory is empty, `-empty` does not need an execute permission on the directory. I deliberately crafted the solution without `cd` and without `-execdir`, so neither our custom test needs execute permission.
- Change `-empty -o` to `! -empty` and you will find directories with lone `.DS_Store` files, but not truly empty directories.

Comment: Wow! This is an impressive and elegant way to perform this operation. I also really appreciate the detailed explanation so that I can understand *how* the solution works instead of just knowing that it does. 