# How do I use xargs to pass arguments as $1, $2, $3, ... to an inline script called with sh -c?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, sh

I want to pass tokens a b c as arguments of a script that will output a - b - c.
If I have a script `dummy.sh` that does `echo "$1 - $2 - $3"` and a `dummy.dat` file containing :

```
a b c
d e f
```

and I want to output

```
a - b - c
d - e - f
```

I can do something like :

```bash
cat dummy.dat | xargs -Iline sh -c "sh dummy.sh line"
cat dummy.dat | xargs -n3 sh dummy.sh
```

But what if I don't want a one-line script, could I just use `sh -c "echo $1 - $2 - $3"` but how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't do `sh -c "echo $1 - $2 - $3"` because the double-quotes will cause your current shell to expand `$1`, `$2` and `$3`. Even if you managed to set these in the current shell beforehand, it still wouldn't be a good general way because the result of the expansion would be *interpreted* by `sh` as shell code. Unless you want it to be interpreted as shell code, don't do this.

`xargs -Iline sh -c "sh dummy.sh line"` is similarly flawed: `line` will be interpreted by the outer `sh`. What if it happens to be `; rm -f /important/file` or `$(shutdown)`? It's like [embedding `{}`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). Don't.

If you want to provide some values, provide as arguments to the `sh` itself:

```
<dummy.dat xargs -n3 sh -c 'echo "$1 - $2 - $3"' sh
```

The second `sh` is explained here: [What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690) The single-quotes protect `$1`, `$2` and `$3` from being expanded by the current shell. `sh` gets the shell code exactly as it is within the single-quotes: `echo "$1 - $2 - $3"`. Arbitrary strings are passed as arguments, expanded only by `sh`, there is no code injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is it :

```
cat dummy.dat | xargs -n3 sh -c 'echo "$0 - $1 - $2"'
```

Comment: Almost. `$0` is not for this. See the section named "Discrepancy?" and further in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1526230/432690).