# Loop of screens with a loop inside does not pick variable values

Tags: linux, shell, python, bash-scripting

How can we execute a loop of screens, each of them executing a loop so that it picks both inner and outer variables?

Consider this:

```bash
# does not print i
for i in 1 2; do
     screen -dmS screen-${i} bash -c 'for j in 1 2; do
          echo screen-${i}-iter-${j}
     done; exec bash'
done
```

This one does not work because the non-interpolating quotes imply the variables inside are intrinsic to `bash -c`, right? So `${i}` is empty.

Consider also:

```bash
# does not print j
for i in 1 2; do
     screen -dmS screen-${i} bash -c "for j in 1 2; do
          echo screen-${i}-iter-${j}
     done; exec bash"
done
```

The second one also does not work because the interpolating quotes imply interpolation outside of `bash -c`. So `${j}` is empty.

**How can I get around this issue?** Is it more appropriate to do it in another language?

I tried Python but could not get around the screens dying when the python script completed. So I couldn't see what is in the screen. Anyway, the screen has to stay open once whoever is calling it dies. My attempt in python follows for completeness.

```python
import subprocess

def screen(i):
    proc = subprocess.Popen('screen -S screen-'+str(i), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    command = f"for j in 1 2; do\necho screen-{i}-iter-${{j}}\ndone; exec bash\n"
    proc.stdin.write('{}'.format(command).encode('utf-8'))

for i in range(2):
    screen(i)
```

Comment: You can concatenate strings quoted differently: `"screen-${i}"'-iter-${j}'`. Here `${i}` is double-quoted, `${j}` is single-quoted. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, this works very well. I'll accept this if you put it in an answer. I can post an answer if you don't feel like doing it. ```bash
for i in 1 2; do
     screen -dmS screen-${i} bash -c "for j in 1 2; do
          echo screen-${i}"'-iter-${j}'"
     done; exec bash"
done
```

Comment: I feel a bit dumb now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings quoted differently (or not quoted at all). E.g. in `"screen-${i}-"iter'-${j}'` there is double-quoted `screen-${i}-`, unquoted `iter` and single quoted `-${j}`. This way you can tell the shell to expand `${i}` but not `${j}`. If the value of `$i` is `1` then the resulting word will be `screen-1-iter-${j}`.

In your particular case where `$i` takes numerical values and `$IFS` is the default one, just mixing the quotes will work.

However, with `bash -c` (or `sh -c` or `ssh` or anything that takes shell code as an argument) embedding a variable expanded by the outer shell is as flawed as [embedding `{}` expanded by `find` or `xargs`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618), especially when the variable comes from an untrusted source.

For example if the value of your `$i` was `; rm -f /important/file;` and you let the outer shell expand it and embed the result in the string that is about to be interpreted as shell code, then  `bash -c` spawned by `screen` would interpret code containing `echo screen-; rm -f /important/file;` and it would try to remove the `/important/file`.

With `bash -c` (or `sh -c`) the right general way is like this:

```
i=whatever
bash -c '
   for j in 1 2; do
      echo "screen-${1}-iter-${j}"
   done
' my-bash "$i"
```

(where `my-bash` is an [arbitrary string](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)). Now the expanded value of `$i` is passed to `bash` as an extra argument. Inside the shell code you retrieve it with `${1}` (or `$1`). The inner shell *will not* interpret the value as shell code.

Always prefer static shell code; pass variables as arguments or in the environment.

Also note I [properly double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) `$i` for the outer shell and `screen-${1}-iter-${j}` for the inner shell. In your first snippet the outer shell sees unquoted `screen-${i}` and the inner shell sees unquoted `screen-${i}-iter-${j}`. You get away with this because `1` and `2` are safe values (at least with the default `$IFS`). Still, IMO it's easier and less error-prone to always quote right by habit than to think each time if possible values are safe.